# For which values of $k$ the equation represents an ellipse

Tags: geometry

For which values of $k$ the following equation represents an ellipse:
$$kx(x+2) + 2y(x-2y+1) + 1 = 0?$$

Comment: Yes, i did a typo... I just corrected it.

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: This will give you a little clue https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bvh8ti52p0

Comment: Should i get rid of the x*y factor and keep only x^2 and y^2?

Answer (score 1):

We have:
$$kx^2+2xy-4y^2+2kx+2y+1=0$$
The [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#Discriminant) of the equation is
$$2^2-4(-4)k=4+16k$$
$$4+16k<0\iff k<-\frac14$$
i.e. it represents an ellipse when $k<-\frac14$.